# how to create a SIP request with specific header fields values

Tags: java, php, python, sip

I'm an intern at a telecommunications operator and my task is to create an application that enables me to send sip (session initiation protocol) requests with the header fields values that I specify. For example generate a register request with the via, from, to, contact and authentication header fields values that I supply.

PS:
I don't want to create a hole sip client, I just want to create register and invite messages with specific header field values.

I've found this method (level7systems.co.uk/en/blog/Click+to+Call+with+PHP-SIP) to be relevant but I'm not sure if it's capable of doing what I need exactly

Is this possible using php?

If not what would be the best programming language to create such an application?

Comment: Starting to create a simple SIP client is like opening Pandora's box. But why don't you start over here: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP_Tutorial. Good Luck!

Comment: i don't want to create a hole sip client , i just want to create register and invite messages with specific header field values , i found this method (http://level7systems.co.uk/en/blog/Click+to+Call+with+PHP-SIP) to be relevant but i'm not sure if it's capable of doing what i need exactly